# What's wrong with my td sizes?

Tags: html

```
<div id="scadenta" style="width:191px; overflow:hidden; border:1; height:90px;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%;"><input type="text"></input></td>
            <td style="width:20%;"><input type="text"></input></td>
            <td style="width:40%;"><input type="text"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is a testing layout i use for one of my tables. It's supposed to have 2 big columns hugging a smaller one. The problem is the tr and td sizes just don't work. I get the all the TDs the same size and almost as large as the whole table. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code or what else could be causing it to behave like this?

Comment: check the size of your input box, maybe that is problem

Comment: try <td width="40%"> instead of style. and input should be <input type="text" />. and also sizes of the inputs together are probably larger than 191px

Comment: Sometimes when you use 100% in pourcentages IE does not like it. I'm not sure for other browser. Try 40% + 19% + 40%. It might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to set a width for your'inputs, otherwise they're set to the browsers default size. take a look at [this jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/SQLYP/) with `style="width:90%;"` set on the inputs (using 100% will make the inputs bigger than the `td`s because of the default-padding - see the [box-model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for more information about this).

note that i also removed the closing `</input>`-tags and made them empty elements (`<input ... />`) like it should be (but this has nothing to do wirth your question).

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch. It worked great except i used a fixed size for the outer input fields because i wanted it to neatly contain a date string. I was unaware of the default size of the input, thought it would fit into the TD.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong... Your td's are styling just fine. They problems lays in the fact that your are setting the table width to 100% AND to 191px AND you are overflowing the table. It's all contradicting. Just start again, remove the width and style and set a border around the td's, that will show you that they will take the correct width.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text"></input>` is simply wrong. Either do `<input type="text" />` or just `<input type="text">`.

Another problem is the default width of the input fields. You are only providing 191px width overall, but one input field almost fills that width. So putting an input field into 20% of 191px will simply extend the `td` so that it fits.

Answer (score 0):

the `input` tag has a set minimum width that is being applied by the browser, you can either increase the size of your div or declare the input type size to be 100%.

```
input {
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change from `<input type="text"></input>`
to `<input type="text" />`